# Using template functions with numbers

Tags: c++

I created template function which allows me to call it with any type of a number, int, double etc...

To call this function, I need to know a number, and to get this number, I read it from the console (`std::cin`).

I was wondering - what's the purpose of using template, if I have to declare variable type to pass it to the function anyway? I mean, I won't be asking user what type of number he wants to pass, and I surely won't do the switch loop for all data types to call function differently.

If anything is not clear enough, let me provide some quick example:

```
template <typename T>
T sum(T a, T b)
{
   return a + b;
}

int main()
{
   using namespace std;
   int a, b; // here, this line

   cout << "Provide first number: ";
   cin >> a;
   cout << "Provide second number: ";
   cin >> b;
   sum(a, b);
}
```

I've been thinking about creating another template function like `loadVariable()`, returning the loaded variable like:

```
template <typename T>
T loadVariable(string text)
{
   T var = new T;
   cout << text;
   cin >> var;
   return var;
}
```

And then just do something like this:

```
int main()
{
   using namespace std;
   sum(loadVariable("Provide first number: "), loadVariable("Provide second number: ");
}
```

However, it looks pretty ugly.

Is this a good practice to use this kind of function?

Or maybe there is some other cool way I'm not aware of?

Comment: in a nutshell, is your question "what's the purpose of using template" ?

Comment: Templates are for *compile-time* flexibility regarding types, e.g. to build algorithms that can be used on different types, not to allow runtime choice of type (which makes sense, since C++ types are a compile-time-only concept); your question would require a *variant* type, which is a completely different thing.

Comment: As @MatteoItalia said, the point is that you do not know the type of the data which user will insert, because you have to run your code to know it. Templates, instead, are useful to create code that is checked when you compile.

Answer (score 3):

Templates help to avoid code duplication [(Do not repeat yourself)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) from the development and maintenance perspective (although the compiler will generate code for each specialization).  They are also used to perform various compile time tasks versus run time tasks using [template metaprogramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming).

Since C++ is statically typed the type must be known at compile time so it must be declared.  See boost::variant for a class that can contain one of many types.

I think your question here with templates is more of an issue with a statically typed vs. dynamically typed language.  I have not checked it, but I think the loadVariable() concept will not compile as the template parameter is not specified and the compiler can not derive the specialization from the call itself.  You would have to have `loadVariable<int>()` or `loadVariable<double>()` where the template parameter is specified.

The question would be do you need to distinguish between an integer or floating point type.  Because you could declare your input variables as double which can contain either.

This may be code just for example purposes of the post, but is this function a memory leak?

```
template <typename T>
T loadVariable(string text)
{
   T var = new T;
   cout << text;
   cin >> var;
   return var;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The point of using a template is that somewhere else in your code you might want to do `sum` with two different type variables. Of course, if you know that your code is so simple that you'll only ever call `sum` with types `int`, then you may very well just use define `sum` to take `int`s instead of as a template.

Your second example with `loadVariable` wouldn't work as you've described it because you would need to specify the template argument:

```
sum(loadVariable<float>("Provide first number: "), loadVariable<float>("Provide second number: "));
```

You could of course write this like so:

```
float a = loadVariable<float>("Provide first number: ");
float b = loadVariable<float>("Provide second number: ");
sum(a, b);
```

Template arguments have to be known at compile-time. Templates are a compile-time construct.  You can always know the types of the arguments you're passing to a function at some point in your code. The point of template functions is not to accept variables whose types can somehow vary. Types *cannot* vary. They are also compile-time constructs. The point of template functions is to give a generic implementation of a function for different types so that it may be called in various places throughout your program.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to create a function to sum two 32-bit integers, you needn't use a template. You use templates when you need to perform the same operations in many different types. For example, say you want to implement a function that returns the smallest among two elements. Lets call it `min`. In your program, you might have many calls of the `min` function, with different types of parameters every time. If you don't use templates, your code will look like this:

```
int min( int a, int b ) { ... }
long min( long a, long b ) { ... }
long long min( long long a, long long b ) { ... }
...
...
...
```

Isn't it easier to just do:

```
template< typename T >
T min( T a, T b ) { return a < b; }
```

In your case, where you just need to sum to integers, there is no need to use a template, as the parameter of your function will always be an `int`.

To sum up, templates offer you **compile-time** flexibility (@Stephane Rolland), meaning that they are almost useless in run-time.

Answer (score 0):

i couldn't answer all the use of template, but just give a example:
when we write a function with array formal arguments like:

```
void foo( int arr[] );
```

If,the precise value of the array bound is important, you maybe do this:

```
void foo(int (&arr)[12] );
```

foo() will accept only arrays of size 12!
template will be useful：

```
template <int n>   
void average( int (&ary)[n] ); // let compiler deduce n for us
```

a more traditional solution is

```
void average_n( int ary[], int size );
```

Of course, we can combine the two approaches:

```
template <int n>
inline void average( int (&ary)[n] )
    { average_n( ary, n ); }
```

refer:C++ Common Knowledge:Essential Intermediate Programming,Item 6. Array Formal Arguments